I want to include a caption but it gives the "not in outer par mode" error
I am using overleaf and I used the "insert figure" button (editor toolbar) to put an image, it gave this code:
 \begin{figure}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{imagem 1 sbrt 2024.png}
     \caption{Enter Caption}
   \label{fig:enter-label} \end{figure}

But on the \centering line it gives the "not in outer par mode" error, when I remove it it gives the error again in the next line and so on.
I tried putting just \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{imagem 1 sbrt 2024.png} with no \begin{figure} command and it worked.
The thing is that I want to add a nice caption there, with a bit of research I found out I am forced to use either \begin{figure} or \begin{table}, so I searched a bit more and put the [h] on the first line of the sample:
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{imagem 1 sbrt 2024.png}
\caption{Enter Caption}
\label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}

Still no use. I tried using the \captionof{}{} command too but it asks for two arguments and I have no idea how to use it. I just want a caption and image centered, nothing more.

EDIT: Sorry I went to sleep and woke up just now, hope this question is still active: I solved my problem with lines 133-137, but the same thing happened in lines 152-163 when I tried to add a table:
https://www.overleaf.com/4611712224rhtdrshtdrrn#096ea4

EDIT 2: I could find a solution doing this, will write here to be documented:
To fit the image and put the caption:
\begin{center}
 \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{name of the image file}

     {\small caption text}
\end{center}

The text is positioned to look like a normal caption.
To put the 4x5 table I used this:
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
Table I. Title of the table.  
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{||c | c | c | c | c ||} 
 \hline
\bf text on cell 11  & text on cell 12 & text on cell 13 & text on cell 14 & text on cell 15 \\
 \hline
 text on cell 21  & text on cell 22 & text on cell 23 & text on cell 24 & text on cell 25  \\
\hline
text on cell 31  & text on cell 32 & text on cell 33 & text on cell 34 & text on cell 35  \\
\hline
text on cell 41  & text on cell 42 & text on cell 43 & text on cell 44 & text on cell 45  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}


The issue is that figures (not captions) can only be added in outer par mode.  This mostly means you have to be outside (almost) all environments or groups, where local and global changes are the same thing.

welcome! you've not shown enough code for anybody to say what the problem is in concrete terms: only that something you've not shown means you're in the wrong mode. note that h is not the same as H. \captionof{figure}{my caption} will give you a caption if you've loaded the appropriate package, but please provide code for a complete but minimal example we can compile to reproduce the problem. you can use e.g. example-image-a for the graphic. also, it is generally easier to avoid strange characters like spaces in path and file names.

You're trying to put the floating figure environment within another environment that restricts the figure environment from floating. It works in the last example because \begin{figure}[H] doesn't float and actually sets the figure in a box where it is coded. So, what bigger/outer environment did you put the figure in?

Sorry guys I didn't understand any of what you said. I will share the whole code then, the image thing I solved in lines 133-137, the image and caption position is good enough as it is. But the same thing happened when I tried to add a table (lines 152-163), so this is the new point I'm stuck now. https://www.overleaf.com/4611712224rhtdrshtdrrn#096ea4

Please provide your code from \documentclass to \end{document}, that will helps to find the error exactly

You could boil down your code to the non-working example `\documentclass{a0poster}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}
\begin{table}
test
\end{table}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}`

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I don't even know if it's different or not, I don't know how to interpret that answer. Well, I found a solution on my own, I will edit the question to post what I could do, hope I can help someone else. But I wont answer my own question because I dont know if it's technical enough.

@BlackWatch The interpretation of the answer is: remove \begin{table} and \end{table}. And replace \caption{...} with \captionof{table}{...}. Same for figures.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I actually tried that before but it didn't work.

@BlackWatch "Didn't work" isn't a very useful error description. I bet if you would make a small reproducible example (including a class and the necessary packages etc.) to show what you tried, we could tell you what the problem is.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz The code I'm working on is already posted, I'm now trying to put two images beside each other, but all the solutions I find on the internet use the "begin figure" command and I'm trying to avoid using it because it gives the "outer par mode" error.

There are only code fragments in your question, not runable examples. For example your question at no point shows that the problem is caused by mdframed. Your question should be understandable without external links.

You can use minipages to put images next to each other.
